# Silverlight ComboBox with two fields per item

Tags: combobox, silverlight-3.0

I want to display a `myItem.title` and `myItem.url` per each item in the `comboBox.ItemsSource` observable collection that gets shown in the comboBox. In other words, I'd like to see each row in the combo box hold and display both pieces of information.

Not sure how to do this or if it's possible.

How would I go about writing the xaml and then make `itemSource.Add()` accept 2 items per actual item?

Thanks for any help!

### EDIT: (solved)

I've come up with this xaml but I have no idea how to access `FiledOne` and `FieldTwo` from code.

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="174" Height="23" Name="addresses_combo" Width="408" SelectionChanged="address_changed">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldOne, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldTwo, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

### EDIT2: (solved)

How can I insert a new line between the two `TextBlock` nodes?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldOne, Mode=OneWay}" />
<TextBlock Text=" \n <--this doesn't work obviously" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldTwo, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

-Or at least make one of them bold and the other regular. So that there would be a clear difference between the two Fields...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the XAML you provided you would need something like this:

```
itemSource.Add(new ItemClass(title,url));
```

Define the ItemClass as something like this:

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public string FieldOne {get;set;}
    public string FieldTwo {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know Silverlight automatically figures out what the `FieldOne` and `FieldTwo` from the xaml are. Thanks! One more thing though, how can I make the comboBox display FieldTwo on a new line? (right now I see "FieldOne FieldTwo", I'd like "FieldOne \n FieldTwo")

Comment: Change the stack panel orientation to Vertical.